# Show all available videos JOINED two tables

Tags: php, join

I have two tables `news` and `video`. Need to show all available videos per `new_id`

Table `news`

| id | title | services |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new_title | Video |
| 2 | new_title_2 | Video |

Table `video`

| id | video_name | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | video_name | 1 |
| 2 | video_name_2 | 2 |
| 3 | video_name_3 | 2 |

My code show me only one video per `new_id`

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `title`, `services` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $services);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $news[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'services' => $services];
}

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT n.id, v.video_name FROM news AS n INNER JOIN video AS v ON n.id = v.new_id');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $video_name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $video[] = ['id' => $id, 'video_name' => $video_name];
    $video[$id] = $video_name;
}

foreach ($news as $new) {
    $service = explode(", ", $new['services']);
    if (in_array('Video', $service)) {
?>
        <!-- HTML5 player video post START -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Card item START -->
            <div class="card">
                <!-- Video -->
                <div class="card-image">
                    <div class="overflow-hidden w-100">
                        <!-- HTML video START -->
                        <div class="player-wrapper overflow-hidden">
                            <video class="player-html" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
                                <source src="../uploads/<?= $video[$new['id']] ?>" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                        <!-- HTML video END -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body px-0 pt-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="post-single-3.html" class="btn-link text-reset fw-bold"><?= $new['title'] ?></a></h5>
                    <!-- Card info -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-divider align-items-center d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        Mar 02, 2022
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card item END -->
        </div>
        <!-- HTML5 player video post END -->
<?php

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `$video[$id]` an array of all the videos, then loop over them.

You shouldn't use the same array for the videos that are indexed by `news.id` and also the list of all videos, since the news IDs will conflict with the array indexes. I've changed `$video[]` to `$all_video[]`

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT n.id, v.video_name FROM news AS n INNER JOIN video AS v ON n.id = v.new_id');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $video_name);
$all_video = [];
$video = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $all_video[] = ['id' => $id, 'video_name' => $video_name];
    $video[$id][] = $video_name;
}

foreach ($news as $new) {
    $service = explode(", ", $new['services']);
    if (in_array('Video', $service)) {
?>
        <!-- HTML5 player video post START -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Card item START -->
            <div class="card">
                <?php foreach($video[$new['id']] as $v) { ?>
                    <!-- Video -->
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <div class="overflow-hidden w-100">
                            <!-- HTML video START -->
                            <div class="player-wrapper overflow-hidden">
                                <video class="player-html" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
                                    <source src="../uploads/<?= $v ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <!-- HTML video END -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                <div class="card-body px-0 pt-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="post-single-3.html" class="btn-link text-reset fw-bold"><?= $new['title'] ?></a></h5>
                    <!-- Card info -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-divider align-items-center d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                        Mar 02, 2022
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card item END -->
        </div>
        <!-- HTML5 player video post END -->
<?php

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Now show me one video for `new_id = 1` this is okay and 3 videos for `new_id = 2` plus one video without source. These 3 videos for `new_id = 2` two videos are duplicated one is okay. And this is case if I move `<?php foreach($video[$new['id']] as $v) { ?>` above `<div class="col-md-4">` and close } under last </div>

Comment: That's the problem I mentioned at the end. Don't use the same array.

Comment: What should I do? Do you mean don't use `$video[] = ['id' => $id, 'video_name' => $video_name];` and `$video[$id][] = $video_name;` same name `$video`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show two different variables.

Comment: Yes, now this working. I thought it need to be the same name, that it was the same array. Thank you @Barmar